# What is better for developing a game

Tags: php, jquery, flash, game-engine

I have good command on jquery and js and PHP but i dont know the flash. But what i have seen is, there are games in flash not in jquery or js.
Please tell me what would be better for me to go for a game development. i have little bit knowledge of Java too.

Comment: Count yourself now for javascript game developer. Best way to start.

Answer (score 1):

There are games in jQuery -- here's 10 simple ones with source code http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/04/13/17-jquery-powered-web-games-with-source-code/

Even popular old games (such as Quake,Doom) have been ported to javascript/HTML5.

Flash is no longer the only way to do things, but for your question it really depends on what you plan to do. There still are some things that flash is required for.

**edit:** here is a comparison between some js game engines https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

Comment: +1 for the game engines link. thx.